# Deployed .net app on new machine and getting "The system cannot execute the specified program"

Tags: .net, .net-2.0

I have a .net console app that launches excel.  I have it working on my development enviornment, but I can't get it running on my production environment.  When I try to run it I receive the following error "The system cannot execute the specified program".  I have installed .net 2.0 sp2 on my production server.  Any ideas?

Thank you,

Code

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 

  DateTime priceDate; 
  bool runningForMidDay; 
  if (args.Length == 0) 
  { 
   priceDate = DateTime.Now; 
   runningForMidDay = false; 
  } 
  else 
  { 
     if (args[0].ToString() == "-?") 
     { 
        Console.WriteLine("This application..."); 
        Console.ReadLine(); 
        return; 
     } 
     if (!DateTime.TryParse(args[0].ToString(), out priceDate)) 
        priceDate = DateTime.Now; 
     if (!bool.TryParse(args[1].ToString(), out runningForMidDay)) 
        runningForMidDay = false; 
  } 
  if (runningForMidDay) 
  { ... } 
  else 
  { ... } 
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using? Are you sure your console app is .NET 2.0?

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
{
DateTime priceDate;
bool runningForMidDay;
if (args.Length == 0)
{
 priceDate = DateTime.Now;
 runningForMidDay = false;
}
else
{
 if (args[0].ToString() == "-?")
 {
  Console.WriteLine("This application...");
  Console.ReadLine();
  return;
 }
if (!DateTime.TryParse(args[0].ToString(), out priceDate))
 priceDate = DateTime.Now;
if (!bool.TryParse(args[1].ToString(), out runningForMidDay))
 runningForMidDay = false;
}
if (runningForMidDay)
{
 ..
}
else
{
 .
}

If I run at the console "name.exe -?", then I still get the same error

Comment: I don't see anything that launches Excel in there, but it's hard to read as a comment. The code should go in your question and use the code formatting layout.

Comment: thank you.  Still learning stack overflow

Comment: Welcome to the site! I answered my own first question also. Did you notice that you can edit your own question after you ask it? (That's how you could have placed that code in the question.) Others (with enough rep points) can also edit your questions and answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They say there is no such thing as a dumb question, just dumb people.  Well that is the case here.  I had an error in my config file.  I have corrected the config file and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this sort of thing happen previously when the C runtime libraries aren't installed on the deployment machine; normally they're not necessary, but they may be required since your app launches Excel.

Comment: Yes,  I know that excel 2003 is installed on the server

Comment: If the console app doesn't even launch, then it wouldn't matter if Excel was installed or not.