# The system cannot execute the specified program

Tags: c#

I have Developed one console application for generating report in excel file format, in my machine it is working fine but when i am deploying it on server its showing

> `The system cannot execute the specified program`

Please give me the solution.

Comment: does your server have excel installed ? if yes check the permissions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917869/deployed-net-app-on-new-machine-and-getting-the-system-cannot-execute-the-spec

Comment: Please add a code sample and where the exception is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tag was missing in the App.Config file, Placing proper tag works fine.

Comment: please add additional information if you can provide.This is not only the answer the particular person.In future may refer this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like .NET Framework is missing.

Comment: I have .Net Framework in My Server, but still its getting problem.

Answer (score 1):

There May be two following reasons of failure

1. As Kamil said - Missing Dot net framework or
2. your program is failing to add OLE object as MS office is unavailable.

Check these first and if it doesnt help then post the code.

Comment: I have checked both the things , but Problem is not getting solved